# подмена ip через curl

Tags: php, curl

Можно ли при получении данных с сайта через curl , что бы запрос шел через ip пользователя который запустил скрипт, а не сервера?

Comment: Нет. Если только на стороне пользователя Вы не подняли прокси, через который по его же (пользователя) согласию и пускаете curl в сеть. Если нужен именно ip пользователя, запрос можно делать клиентскими скриптами, но только к ресурсам, которые это разрешают.

Answer (score 1):

**Нет.** Но вы можете заставить клиентский браузер выполнить запрос «от себя» и передать на ваш сервер полученный ответ.

---

Например, php отдаёт страницу с подключением jQuery и таким JS:

```
function gotData(r) { // эта ф-я получит в браузере данные от ВК
    $.ajax({
        url:'vash.site/receiver.php',
        data:r,
        method:'POST',
    });
}

// запрос к "тому" сайту от клиента
$.ajax({
    url:'https://api.vk.com/method/users.get',
    data: {user_ids: 1, fields:'photo_100'},
    dataType:'jsonp',
    method:'POST',
    success: gotData,
});
```

А другой php (или этот же) принимает чуть позже ответ, переданный клиентом.

Comment: а как это можно реализовать?

Comment: @LoginIP обновил ответ

Comment: можно ли подменить user agent клиента при запросе к "тому" сайту?

Comment: `User-agent` подменить, скорее всего, не получится.

Comment: $.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(request) {
    request.setRequestHeader("User-Agent","InsertUserAgentStringHere");
  }
}); а это код не подменит UA ?

Comment: @LoginIP, я был бы рад, если вы попробовали сами, на разных браузерах, и поделились результатом.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать вот так:

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("REMOTE_ADDR: $ip", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: $ip"));
```

> Но это будет работать, только, если на той стороне полагаются на эти переменные.

**UPD**
Как ответил @Sergiks будет 100% решение, если JS не запрещен религией.
PHP - серверная сторона. JS - клиентская. Как выход через AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Curl, который далеко не у всех пользователей есть? 

Может https://github.com/padolsey-archive/jquery.fn/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax
подойдет?